# Type checking fun with function interfaces parameters in VB.Net

Tags: .net, compiler-construction, interface, parameters, typechecking

Visual Studio seems to stop type checking function parameters when one of the parameters is an interface.

Consider the following:

```vb
' An interface and the class that implements it:
Public Interface IA

End Interface

Public Class A
    Implements IA
End Class


' Another reference type for the demonstration:
Public Class MyReferenceType

End Class


' A function that uses IA as the type of one of its parameters:
Private Function SomeFunc(ByVal a As IA, ByVal r As MyReferenceType)
    Return Nothing
End Sub
```

And here is an example of the type checking problems:

```vb
Private Sub Example()
    Dim a As IA = New A
    Dim r As New MyReferenceType

    ' Some other random reference type, choose any 
    ' other reference type you like
    Dim list As New List(Of String)

    ' Each of these calls to SomeFunc compile without errors.
    SomeFunc(r, r)
    SomeFunc(r, a)
    SomeFunc(list, r)
    SomeFunc(list, a)

    ' Does not compile due to type mismatch
    'SomeFunc(list, list)
End Sub
```

As my comments suggest, this code compiles fine, with no errors in the editor either. If I execute the program though I get `System.InvalidCastException`, which isn't a surprise at all. I guess this is a type checking bug in the compiler? I'm using Visual Studio 2005, so is this fixed in a later version of VS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's because you've got [Option Strict](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx) off. If you turn Option Strict on to start with, your code fails to compile, exactly as we'd expect.

Note that this:

```
SomeFunc(list, a)
```

is not like this:

```
SomeFunc(list, list)
```

In the first case, when Option Strict is off, the compiler is effectively inserting a cast for you. After all, a value of type `IA` *can* be a `MyReferenceType`.

In the second case, a value of `List(Of String)` cannot *ever* be compatible with `MyReferenceType` (with the arguable exception of a value of `Nothing`...), so even with Option Strict off, compilation fails. The compiler won't let you try something which can't ever work.

Moral of the story: for better type checking, turn Option Strict on.

Comment: You are correct! I must have turned off Option Strict off somehow, MSDN says the default state is on.